# I am getting an error in my Python program, that seems to only occur every now and again

Tags: python, replit

I am writing a quiz in Python for a school project, however I have hit a road block. Every now and then, when I run through it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 55, in <module>
    random.shuffle(questions[question]["answers"])
KeyError: None
```

Now the weird thing is, this line works most of the time. I have run through the program multiple times, and most of the time it gets to the end without any errors. I can't see what would possibly be causing this. Here is the full code of my project:

```
# Lia's quiz. Questions are subject to change
# Used https://www.randomtriviagenerator.com/ to generate the questions and answers

import random

# The questions dictionary. Each question has a list of possible answers, the correct answer, a comment, and the amount of points you get for it. I'll add more later
questions = {
  0: {
    "question":
    "Which country technically fought a war agaisnt a type of bird?",
    "answers": ['Angola', 'Australia', 'Venezuela', 'Pakistan'],
    "correct": "Australia",
    "comment":
    "The \"Emu\" war was fought in Australia between November and December 1932. The Emus won.",
    "points": 1
  },
  1: {
    "question": "What sea lies between Greece and Turkey?",
    "answers":
    ['Ionian Sea', 'Aegean Sea', 'Mediterranean Sea', 'Adriatic Sea'],
    "correct": "Aegean Sea",
    "comment":
    "The Aegean Sea lies between the east coast of Greece and the west coast of Turkey.",
    "points": 1
  },
  2: {
    "question":
    "Complete the name of the 2012 album by Lana Del Rey: Born to...",
    "answers": ['...Live', '...Die', '...Love', '...Cry'],
    "correct": "...Die",
    "comment":
    "Born to Die is the second studio album and major-label debut by American singer-songwriter Lana Del Rey, released in January 2012.",
    "points": 1
  },
}

# Set the score to zero
score = 0

# Get a random question, and make sure it hasn't been asked before
questions_done = []
def question_randomiser():
  question = random.randint(0, 2)
  if (questions_done.count(question) > 0):
    question_randomiser()
    return
  questions_done.append(question)
  return question

# Main loop, repeats as many times as you want. I intentionally made it not rely on the amount of questions there are, so each quiz is a little different.
for i in range(3):
  # Get a random question, and make sure it hasn't been asked before
  question = question_randomiser()
  # Shuffle the answers in a different order
  random.shuffle(questions[question]["answers"])
  a = questions[question]["answers"][0]
  b = questions[question]["answers"][1]
  c = questions[question]["answers"][2]
  d = questions[question]["answers"][3]

  # Ask the question
  print(f"\n\n{questions[question]['question']}")
  # Get the user's answer
  ans = input(f"1. {a}, 2. {b}, 3. {c}, 4. {d}. \n")
  # Check if the answer is valid
  if (ans.isnumeric() == 0):
    print(
      "\nERROR: The value you input must be a number between 1 and 4, written in decimal form with no punctuation. Try again: \033[F"
    )
    continue
  ans = int(ans)
  if (ans > 4 or ans < 1):
    print(
      "\nERROR: The value you input must be a number between 1 and 4, written in decimal form with no punctuation. Try again:\033[F"
    )
    continue

  # Check if the answer is correct.
  if ((ans + -1) == questions[question]["answers"].index(
      questions[question]["correct"])):
    print(f"Correct. {questions[question]['comment']}\nPlus {questions[question]['points']} point(s).")
  else:
    print(f"Incorrect. {questions[question]['comment']}")
```

I am using Replit if that counts for anything. I am relatively new to Python so I apologise if there is a painfully obvious fix.

Comment: `if (questions_done.count(question) > 0):
    question_randomiser();
    return` did you mean `return question_randomiser()`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi that seems to have worked. I didn't properly understand recursion in python. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your function `question_randomiser` is potentially incorrect:

```
def question_randomiser():
  question = random.randint(0, 2)
  if (questions_done.count(question) > 0):
    question_randomiser()
    return
  questions_done.append(question)
  return question
```

`return` by itself will return None, which is your problem. `return question_randomiser()` might work properly for your use case.

Comment: that seems to have worked. I didn't properly understand recursion in python. Thank you